# .to_date method failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using rails 3.2.16 and ruby 1.9.3
I get this error from the localhost browser after rails s.

```
 undefined method `to_date' for nil:NilClass
```

like this

```
NoMethodError in Products#new
Showing /Users/main/railscasts-episodes/episode-350/store- 
after/app/views/products/_form.html.erb where line #27 raised:
undefined method `to_date' for nil:NilClass
```

in irb> mode it works only when I

```
require 'date'
```

Now my question is about my rails project. In which file in my project I should add

```
require 'date'
```

I added it into my model it did not work. Or, maybe I need to install any specific gem? to make this work

Comment: It will *never* work if what you're calling it on is nil. Well, unless you add it to NilClass, but you know what I mean.

Comment: Can you just post your new.html.erb/_form.html.erb and Products_Controller.rb files?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have isn't an issue with `to_date`, it's a problem with the object you're trying to perform the method on

Your issue will either be:

> - You have not declared the variable / object
> - Your variable / object is not populated with any data

I'd highly recommend posting the controller action you're using to invoke the `to_date` method. Obviously, there may be an issue with the way you're calling it, but the immediate issue is you're trying to deal with an unpopulated variable